# Удалить td из каждой строки tr

Tags: javascript

Здравствуйте.

Нужно удалить 3 td из каждой строки. При клике нужно, чтобы удалялося 3 строки и три столбца. К примеру, была таблица 9х9, при клике стало 6х6, еще раз клик - 3х3.

На данный момент удаляются только строки.
Моя реализация: http://jsfiddle.net/qjjsprda/4/

Comment: Да и строки удаляются, но не 3, а половина от общего числа :)

Comment: при клик**Е**

Comment: @Etki вы боретесь с ветряными мельницами)

Comment: @DreamChild мы все этим занимаемся.

Comment: @Etki за всех говорить не стану, но за себя могу сказать, что борьбы с ветряными мельницами в сфере правописания стараюсь избегать ввиду неблагодарности и безнадежности этой затеи

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Наверное, вам подойдет такой вариант:

```
function add(toAdd) {
    var table = document.getElementById('table');
    var count = table.getElementsByTagName("tr").length;

    for(var i = 0; i < count + toAdd; i++) {
       var noRowToAdd = i < count;
       var row = noRowToAdd ? 
           table.rows[i] :
           table.insertRow(i);

        var low = noRowToAdd ? count : 0;
        var high = noRowToAdd ? toAdd: count + toAdd;
        for(var k = 0; k < high; k++) {            
            var x = row.insertCell(low + k);            
        }
    }
}

function del(toDel) {
    var table = document.getElementById('table');
    var count = table.getElementsByTagName("tr").length;

    if(count - toDel < 3)
        return;

    for(var i = 0; i < toDel; i++) {
        table.deleteRow(count - i - 1);
    }

    var newCount = count - toDel;

    for(var i = 0; i < newCount; i++) {
        for(var k = newCount + toDel; k > newCount; k--) {           
            table.rows[i].deleteCell(k - 1);
        }
    }       
}
```

[Пример](http://jsfiddle.net/0s6pxqh3/)